# Why doesn't my local area connection have a valid ip configuration?

Tags: windows-7

I started my computer today without being able to connect to the internet for some very odd reason. As the title says, that is the name of problem that Network and Sharing Center says on Win7.

It is weird though, because every time I troubleshoot the problem it cycles through two answers. One time it will be the name of the problem above, and the next time it will say that my perfectly fine Ethernet cable is not properly plugged in or may be broken. It also showed a 3rd problem, saying my Realteak PCIe GBE Family Controller (gigabyte Ethernet card) was bad so I reinstalled that and the error went away but not the problem.

I'm running Windows 7 64bit and connecting to the internet through a Ethernet cable obviously. My Linksys router is fine, and I'm using another computer in the house to type up this problem here.

```
> ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Luke-WIN7-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8168D/8111D Family PCI-E Gigab
it Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 48-5B-39-45-13-87
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::69e4:a47c:962d:10f7%11(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.16.247(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 189291321
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-E4-B3-2B-48-5B-39-45-13-87

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: from a CMD prompt, please cute and paste the output of `ipconfig /all`

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: DHCP seems broken from what I see...

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: I've been having this same problem for weeks and it's driving me crazy! I haven't figured out the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have other computers to test this with? You should try to determine whether this is your router that is malfunctioning or whether it is your computer that has new recent problems.

For your router, you could try to install the latest firmware and when necessary try to reset/reconfigure it to make sure it's back in business. Make sure that DHCP is set up well, or you would need to give your computer it's own static IP address.

For your computer, try obtaining the latest network drivers and make sure the cable is properly connected. Resetting the adapter as well reinstalling any installed firewalls might or might not give a difference. As said before, if DHCP is somehow broken, you might consider want to use a static IP...

Comment: a tcpdump on port 67 might also be useful to see what is going on with DHCP.

Comment: All the other computers are connecting to my network wirelessly fine. My Xbox connects fine through ethernet to my router as well. I tried setting up a static IP but I need to be connected to the network which I can't do.

Comment: @Luke: You don't need an actual connection to be able to configure the static IP.

Comment: From the tutorial on portforward I needed to be connected so I could change he network adapter settings.

Comment: @LukeoX: Not necessary, you can change these with the cable plugged out...

Comment: How should I do it then?

Comment: @LukeoX: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-TCP-IP-settings

Comment: Strangely, the "change adapter settings" button showed up this time and I followed everything in that link and all my settings were to to automatically obtain the IP address already.

Comment: Also I tried to setup a static IP but the DNS server was broken or something so I couldn't enter a specific DNS server.

Comment: @Luke oX: In which way was that broken? Strange, try 8.8.4.4 as a DNS server. (It's Google DNS)

Comment: Well in the tutorial it said to use the same DNS which I saw in the ipconfig /all, but the server was "fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1" and when I try to enter that Window says,"You are trying to paste a malformed IP address into this field."

Also the defualt gateway shown in ipconfig /all is completely blank.

Comment: @Luke: Your DHCP is broke so DNS won't show a DNS server; you need to configure IPv4, not IPv6.

Comment: I was trying to configure IPv4 but I need a DNS server and defualt gateway to make it static.

Comment: @LukeoX: Default gateway is your router and DNS server is 8.8.4.4.

Comment: Ipconfig /all wont show my default gateway or my router IP.

Comment: @LukeoX: You are supposed to know that IP, the default one is in the manual of your router. You might need to reset your router (instructions also in the manual) in order for the IP to be the default IP. Who knows, resetting your router might fix your problem in the first place. When in doubt/despair, try contacting your ISP to guide/help you (perhaps, they come at home to do it for a fee). Anyhow, Linksys usually has `192.168.0.1` or `192.168.1.1` so try those...

Comment: I found my router's IP and I've tried a bunch of DNS server's with no luck. I'm installing OpenDNS on my router right now to see if that does anything. I have pressed the reset button on the back of my router a few times with no luck but I'll see if I can find the manual and see what it says.

Comment: @LukeoX: Okay, good plan. Here is the way you need to fill in the static IP configuration: In the first field, enter the router IP but ending with a random number like `123` so it is your IP. In the second field called subnet, enter `255.255.255.0`. In both the gateway and DNS fields, enter the router IP.

Comment: Yeah I've have OpenDNS on my router and its working on my other PCs fine. I've tried the DNS servers on my PC, and I tried the static config that you posted, but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Both IPv4 and IPv6 have standard methods for address autoconfiguration. For link-local addressing IPv4 uses the special block 169.254.0.0/16 as described in RFC 3927 while IPv6 hosts use the prefix fe80::/10.

Most IPv4 hosts use link-local addressing (IPv4LL) only **as a last resort when a DHCP server is unavailable**. An IPv4 host otherwise uses its DHCP-assigned address for all communications, global or link-local. One reason is that IPv4 hosts are not required to support multiple addresses per interface, although many do. Another is that not every IPv4 host implements distributed name resolution (e.g., multicast DNS), so discovering the autoconfigured link-local address of another host on the network can be difficult. However, discovering the DHCP-assigned address of another host also requires either distributed name resolution or a unicast DNS server with this information, and some networks feature DNS servers that are automatically updated with DHCP-assigned host and address information.

Answer (score 0):

Update the BIOS.

I have seen Network Card problems on laptops running Windows 7 and 8, BIOS update and latest chipset driver resolved the issue. Check you BIOS/UEFI firmware version by running the command: wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion

Check if it is the latest version or not. Be careful with the BIOS update (You will brick the laptop if the BIOS update is interrupted or goes wrong, also power cut during BIOS update will brick the laptop)!